# Restricted logins + almost all ports closed : secure?

Tags: linux, security, firewall

### Context :

I plan to travel.
I want to make a little cloud with my personal server. I wish I could d/l some of my files and eventually upload some files which will not be executed and the whole is protected by a non trivial password.

I am the only human user.

Netfilter : all ports closed but port 443.
No scripts to execute.
Apache with lowest privileges possible.

I've disabled all remote logins with a script automatically executing whenever a user tries to log in /etc/profile (it basically kick out anyone trying to connect since I just want to be able to connect to the box physically).

But I just have my port 443 opened with apache and a profiled apparmor to be sure Apache doesn't do anything stupid.
No database.

Debian Stable 64 bits updated.

### Question :

Will it suffice to secure my box ?
Did I overlook something ? Any other advices ?

Thanks

Comment: A note about the script in `/etc/profile` : this file has no control over connections, it simply sets up the environment for the Bash shell. However, if your attacker does not require a shell (using a homemade program to handle the SSH connection for instance), that script will not be used. Of course, since you've blocked the SSH port, that's basically not a problem.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith : Even if a shell is not required and bypasses /etc/profile, since no script execution is allowed, it is not a problem either, right ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad topic, but these are my 2 cents:

- Encrypt your disks.
- Don't limit AppArmor to `apache`.
- Provided an organized partition/LVM2 layout, most of the system can be mounted read-only.
- Mount `nodev,nosuid,noexec` everything that does not need those permissions, `apt` and `aptitude` may need temporary execution permissions on `/tmp`, you can add this to your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or in a snippet under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

  ```
  DPkg::Pre-Invoke {"mount -o remount,exec /tmp";};
  DPkg::Post-Invoke {"mount -o remount /tmp";};
  ```
- Use a non-root account, and grant only the required `sudo` permissions to that account.
- If this is going to be exposed to the internet, use `fail2ban` or `denyhosts`.
- Do regular security updates.
- Place logs in a separate partition/logical volume.
- Have backups and test them.
- Plan for a possible compromise.